# $x(x+3)^2y'' -y=0$ - Questions regarding analyticness and irregular/regular singularness at a point

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently in the section in my book dealing with solutions about singular points and Frobenius' Theorem.

For $x(x+3)^2y'' -y=0$, how is $x(x+3)$ singular at 0 (nonanalytic) but $p(x)=(x-0)P(x)=(x-0)(0)$ considered analytic and regular?  Both of these things equal zero.

Is it because the former eliminates the second derivative?

My current understanding of the definition of analytic:
- The function has a Taylor series
- The function is infinitely differentiable
- The function's Taylor series converges somewhere

I'm having a hard time understanding this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: both $x = 0, x = -3$ are regular singular points. every thing else is a regular point.

Answer (score 1):

$x=0$ and $x=-3$ are singular points for the differential equation.  It is the solution of the differential equation which will be non-analytic at these points.  (Of course $x(x+3)^2$ is analytic everywhere.)

Divide to get the differential equation in the form
$$
y'' + 0 y' -\frac{1}{x(x+3)^2} y = 0
$$
First, $0$ is a regular singular point since $0$ is analytic at $0$ (and thus has a pole of order ${}\le 1$), and $-1/x(x+3)^2$ has a pole of order $1$ (and thus has a pole of order ${}\le 2$).

And $-3$ is a regular singular point since $0$ is analytic at $-3$ (and thus has a pole of order ${}\le 1$), and $-1/x(x+3)^3$ has a pole of order $2$ (and thus has a pole of order ${}\le 2$).

At every point except $0$ and $-3$, the differential equation has two linearly independent analytic solutions.  But not at $0$ and $-3$.  There is where you need to apply the theory of regular singular points.

Comment: Thanks GEdgar.  So eliminating the possibility for two linearly independent solutions makes the equation non-analytic at those points?